# Searching "/*" string that is not after //

Tags: tcl

I want to find the line in the file in which the string `/*` is not followed by `//` using tcl regexp.
for example:

```
/* some note
...
...
//
.
.
///*
/*
```

the result should be first and last line. Ignoring  the `///*`.

Comment: If that's what you want, I think you should go for it.

Comment: I have a six-character regex that does just that (with the correct invocation). Show me your attempt and I'll post it (unless someone else posts it first).

Comment: Btw your question is not in line with your title. `/*` not after `//` means not `///*` (ignoring chars between them) and `/*` not followed by `//` means not `/*//` (again, ignoring chars between them). You might want to fix your question

Comment: Also, can you give more examples? Is `/*` always at the beginning of a line?

Comment: No it isn't always in the beginning of a line. It can be in the middle and before it can be writing something.

Comment: @user3383125 Okay, and do you have anything for the other questions I asked? Just to make things clear and avoid having to go back and forth changing things because you meant something and we understand something else.

Answer (score 0):

This does work on your example, but doesn't if the `/*` isn't at the start of the line:

```
set a "/* some note                                                                     
...
...
//
.   
.   
///*
/*"

set re {^/\*.*$}
puts [regexp -all -inline -line $re $a]
```

In fact, it sounds like you'd want `'// /*'` also to be skipped - as in nested comments?

Edit: I added `.*$` to the regular expression, so the rest of the comment lines will be included. The above example now returns this list:

```
{/* some note} /*
```

Comment: However, you don't get the whole line with that.

Answer (score 0):

Tcl's RE engine doesn't have lookbehind (if you want to submit a patch to add it, feel free). That means that the easiest way to find the lines that match what you want is probably to pre-filter.

```
foreach line [split $data "\n"] {
    if {[regexp {/\*} [regsub {//.*} $line ""]]} {
        puts "Found match in $line"
    }
}
```

If you're really doing parsing of some language that includes both of those comment syntaxes, use a real parser. It's much easier than trying to wedge everything into just regular expressions. (Parsers tend to use REs, but usually just very simple ones…)